# Delphi: Referencing a class instance created by TAutoObjectFactory

Tags: delphi, object, automation

We have an application which is also a COM server and can run either as standalone or automated by a COM client.

The COM Class is declared in the following way:

```
type
  TCommandApp = class(TAutoObject, IConnectionPointContainer, ICommandApp)
```

And the Initialization part is as follows:

```
TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TCommandApp, Class_CommandApp, 
                          ciSingleInstance, tmApartment);
```

Which creates an instance of `TCommandApp`. The question is how do I reference the instance of `TCommandApp` created by `TAutoObjectFactory`? (Call its methods etc).

Comment: `TAutoObjectFactory.Create` doesn't create an instance of `TCommandApp`. It creates a factory which can then instantiate `TCommandApp` instances and pass them to the client. At least, that's my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create `TCommandApp` instances the same way COM does, then you should call the factory's [`CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682215.aspx) method, which comes from the `IClassFactory` interface.

```
var
  Factory: IClassFactory;
  App: ICommandApp;

Factory := TAutoObjectFactory.Create(...);
OleCheck(Factory.CreateInstance(nil, ICommandApp, App));
```

Alternatively, you can call the constructor directly:

```
var
  Factory: TComObjectFactory;
  App: TCommandApp;

Factory := TAutoObjectFactory.Create(...);
App := TCommandApp.CreateFromFactory(Factory, nil);
```